# Randomness and precision of Quantum Number Random Generators

Tags: qiskit, quantum-algorithms, cryptography, experimental-realization

I am reading about the problem of generating random quatum numbers, and I am interested in the state of the art in terms of the true randomness these generators achieve.

As far as I know, following reviews like [this one](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2203.00261.pdf) the basic problem is that any quantum device would be affected to some degree by noise in some biased direction, so a myriad of experimental device has been proposed and built to avoid this bias.

However I am a bit confused about the overall success/failure of the program, i.e.

1. Are there **any QRNG clearly superior** to the others?
2. What is the quantitative difference between the **best QRNG and the best classical** one?
3. Are these QRNG random enough? I guess the maximum accuracy is needed for cryptographic purposes. **Are there proofs that they can/cannot be cracked?**

Answer (score 1):

My naive take is that the state of any classical generator may be gigantic but enumerable. Hence the generated sequences should repeat eventually. Perhaps that's overly naive.